# python pytomlpp formatting toml list to show a fixed number of element per line

Tags: python, format, toml

I am using pytomlpp as it it much faster than other toml python package. This package formats list with one element per line while toml or rtoml formats multiple elements per line.
Is there a way to enable 4 or 5 list elements  per line ?
Alternatively is there a python package that can modify a toml file to follow a particular style/format ?

Thanks

I went to the pytomlpp which seems to be quite minimal